# Use a Dialplan to play wav using b-leg in freeswitch

Tags: freeswitch

How do I  configure a DialPlan to play a sound before a call in FreeSwitch?
I've already tried the instructions here: https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Misc._Dialplan_Tools_playback
I'm trying to play ads before every and each call but can't get the file to be played before the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up a HTTP server, which should return your dial plan via a POST request. The wav file should be placed in the freeswitch/conf folder.
For example, configure your freeswitch/conf/autoload_configs/ml_curl.conf.xml  as the following:

```html
<configuration name="xml_curl.conf" description="cURL XML Gateway">
  <bindings>
    <binding name="dialplan">
      <!-- Allow to bind on a particular IP for requests sent -->
      <!--<param name="bind-local" value="$${local_ip_v4}" />-->
      <!-- The url to a gateway cgi that can generate xml similar to
    what's in this file only on-the-fly (leave it commented if you dont
    need it) -->
      <!-- one or more |-delim of configuration|directory|dialplan -->
      <param name="gateway-url" value="http://0.0.0.0:4000/dialplan.xml" bindings="dialplan"/>
      <!-- set this to provide authentication credentials to the server -->
      <!--<param name="gateway-credentials" value="muser:mypass"/>-->
      <!--<param name="auth-scheme" value="basic"/>-->

      <!-- optional: this will enable the CA root certificate check by libcurl to
           verify that the certificate was issued by a major Certificate Authority.
           note: default value is disabled. only enable if you want this! -->
      <!--<param name="enable-cacert-check" value="true"/>-->
      <!-- optional: verify that the server is actually the one listed in the cert -->
      <!-- <param name="enable-ssl-verifyhost" value="true"/> -->

      <!-- optional: these options can be used to specify custom SSL certificates
           to use for HTTPS communications. Either use both options or neither.
           Specify your public key with 'ssl-cert-path' and the private key with
           'ssl-key-path'. If your private key has a password, specify it with
           'ssl-key-password'. -->
      <!-- <param name="ssl-cert-path" value="$${certs_dir}/public_key.pem"/> -->
      <!-- <param name="ssl-key-path" value="$${certs_dir}/private_key.pem"/> -->
      <!-- <param name="ssl-key-password" value="MyPrivateKeyPassword"/> -->
      <!-- optional timeout -->
      <!-- <param name="timeout" value="10"/> -->

      <!-- optional: use a custom CA certificate in PEM format to verify the peer
           with. This is useful if you are acting as your own certificate authority.
           note: only makes sense if used in combination with "enable-cacert-check." -->
      <!-- <param name="ssl-cacert-file" value="$${certs_dir}/cacert.pem"/> -->

      <!-- optional: specify the SSL version to force HTTPS to use. Valid options are
           "SSLv3" and "TLSv1". Otherwise libcurl will auto-negotiate the version. -->
      <!-- <param name="ssl-version" value="TLSv1"/> -->

      <!-- optional: enables cookies and stores them in the specified file. -->
      <!-- <param name="cookie-file" value="$${temp_dir}/cookie-mod_xml_curl.txt"/> -->

      <!-- one or more of these imply you want to pick the exact variables that are transmitted -->
      <!--<param name="enable-post-var" value="Unique-ID"/>-->
    </binding>
  </bindings>
</configuration>
```

Replace 0.0.0.0 with the server IP of your HTTP server.
Bellow there's an example of the dialplan.xml your HTTP server should return:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document type="freeswitch/xml">
  <section name="dialplan">
    <context name="default">
      <extension name=test">
        <condition field="destination_number" expression=".*">    
         <action application="playback" data="/usr/local/freeswitch/conf/test.wav"/>
        </condition>
      </extension>
    </context>
  </section>
</document>
```

Restart freeswitch and try again.
If you need